# How to reset Google Form counter values using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have several Google forms which are reused frequently with around 300 - 400 form submission each time.

Until now, I have two ways to reset form, by hand:

1. Deleting the form while keeping the form editor opened.
2. Select the rows that contain form submissions, right click and choose "Delete ... rows".

With script, I've have no luck finding such method like `form.reset()`. 
The method `.DeleteRows(fromRow, to Row)` just delete the rows, but doesn't affect the counters.

So, how can I use Google apps script to automate the "reset form" task?
 Or, how to mimic the second way in script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working solution, that uses `deleteRows()`. I'm not sure why that didn't work for you, it would be interesting to see your code.

The new Forms product (February 2013) is quite different than the legacy forms - *this solution will work on legacy forms only*.

Anyway, here's what I have, with before & after screenshots. The `tidy()` function can be called by passing in the number of rows to be removed, or you can call it from a menu as demonstrated here. A more complete version of this script is [available as a gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/5014758).

```
/**
 * Standard onOpen provided in script template.
 */
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{name : "Read Data",functionName : "readRows"},
                 {name : "Tidy Form Responses", functionName : "tidy"}];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};

/**
 * Prompt user for the number of form response rows to remove, then delete them.
 * Assumes that the form responses are in the active sheet, that there is one
 * row of 'headers' followed by responses (in row 2).
 *
 * @param {number} thisMany (Optional) The number of rows to remove. If not
 *                          specified, user will be prompted for input.
 */
function tidy(thisMany) {
  if (tidy.arguments.length == 0) {
    thisMany = Browser.inputBox("How many responses should be tidied?");
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.deleteRows(2, thisMany);
}
```

### Before

[image: Spreadsheet with form responses and custom menu]

### During

[image: Script operation, inputBox]

### After

[image: Spreadsheet with 2 fewer form responses]

Comment: This is working for legacy forms, you're right, but it seems that it's not the case anymore with the new forms, the counter doesn't appear in the spreadsheet anymore and deleting the 'grey added rows' has no effect (at least in my test)... Anyway, I think the question was about legacy forms so that's out of subject right now. +1 for this clear demo :-) - note : you could improve it a bit by providing the ability to remove last answers as well, not only the first ones (or even better : any answer by choosing the start number)

Comment: Thanks, @Serge. I put a more complete version in a gist - it can delete all rows. While I could (or anyone who wants it could) be more selective about where to start deleting, I've made the assumption that the oldest responses are the most expendable. As for the new forms, with responses part of the form instead of a spreadsheet, this won't work. Could be added to [the existing API request](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2383).

Comment: Thank @Mogsdad, I've try your code and adjust it a bit, and it works, not only delete the rows but also update the form counter: `//resetInput  
  var shInput = ss.getSheetByName('Input');  
  LastInput = shInput.getLastRow();  
  ss.toast('LastInput in row: '+LastInput); //Confirm the last row  
  shInput.deleteRows(2, LastInput-1);`

Answer (score 2):

Google Forms has created a new form editor (released just a few weeks ago). This new form editor has an option for "Delete all responses." So one option would be to re-create the form in the new form editor. (From a new spreadsheet, click Tools > Create a form).

**Note:** This new form editor isn't available to Google Apps users yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Since I linked the Input sheet with other sheets, which is quite alot of formulas. Re-create the form or link it to another sheet will make formulas broke. That's one of my reason to think about Script option.

Comment: @Phil - The new Forms offering is more than a new editor - the changes are deeper than that. The responses shown in a spreadsheet are copies of source data now stored in the Form service, whereas in the legacy forms the ss was the only store. If you "Review Responses" from the sheet, the report comes from the Form - changes/corrections in the sheet are excluded. Likewise, the "Delete all responses" action warns "Responses already sent to a spreadsheet will not be deleted." So to both clear the Form responses AND sheet requires two actions now.

Comment: ...There is no forms API at this time, but [it's been requested](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2383).