# Purge all records from a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to use onFormSubmit event to 'remotely' delete all the rows in a Google Spreadsheet. For example, when I include the word 'Purge' in a field, then clear all the rows.

I tried this:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var first = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
  var CheckString=e.values[5];

  if (CheckString == ['purge'])
    first.clearContents();

}
```

but I get the error:

```
Start           Function        Error Message                                               Trigger     End
6/3/13 10:01 AM onFormSubmit    ReferenceError: "e" is not defined. (line 4, file "purge4") formSubmit  6/3/13 10:01 AM
```

What can I do about this? (Or if anyone knows a way to wipe a Google Spreadsheet from within Access or Excel VBA then even better!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger function is being passed an event object, but unless you name that object in your parameter list, you will have to access it via `arguments`.

Try this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
```

That's all that's needed to make your function work.

Alternatively, if you want to use `arguments`, you'd have to change your code to do things like this:

```
var CheckString=arguments[0].values[5];
```

You still have other problems though. `Range.clearContents()` will erase all your previous responses, but will also erase the question / header line, and it won't reset the response range.

I've rewritten your script to use a variant of the `tidy()` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15028623/1677912). This will leave your headers, and completely delete the rows containing all previous responses.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var CheckString=e.values[5];

  if (CheckString == ['purge']) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var first = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses");
    var numResponses = first.getDataRange().getNumRows() - 1;
    tidy(first,numResponses);
  }

}

/**
 * Prompt user for the number of form response rows to remove, then delete them.
 * Assumes that the form responses are in the active sheet, that there is one
 * row of 'headers' followed by responses (in row 2).
 *
 * @param {Sheet}  sheet    Sheet to be tidied.
 * @param {number} thisMany (Optional) The number of rows to remove. If not
 *                          specified, user will be prompted for input.
 */
function tidy(sheet,thisMany) {
  if (tidy.arguments.length == 0) {
    // Exception if no sheet provided
    throw new Error( 'Parameter "sheet" not defined' );
  }

  // else we assume we have a Sheet object for first argument

  if (tidy.arguments.length == 1)
    thisMany = Browser.inputBox("How many responses should be tidied?");

  sheet.deleteRows(2, thisMany);
}
```

Comment: perfect.  now to figure out http post to send the purge command from excel!  I'll leap off that bridge when I get to it!

Comment: Just a stupid side note: in Javascript (and Apps Script) you can access a function parameters even without naming it. Just check the `arguments` array.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu - agreed, although it's less friendly for self-confessed noobs. I've updated the answer with an example of using `arguments`. (Was already using it in `tidy()`.)

Comment: @Mogsdad I didn't thought this comment deserved to be part of the answer. That's why I called it a "stupid side note". But ok, looks more complete now :)